# Flask-SQLAlchemy queries

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having issues with a seemingly simple sqlalchemy query using Flask.

I have a table called Links and within that table there are columns called 'id', 'author_id', 'link', and 'group'. My models.py looks like this:

```
class Links(db.Model):

__tablename__='links'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
link = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=True)
group = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)


def __init__(self, author_id=None, link=None, group=None):
    self.author_id = author_id
    self.link = link
    self.group = group

def __repr__(self):
    return'<Link %r>' %(self.link)
```

I would like to return the values of all groups associated with the user that is logged into the application. Here is my views.py file:

```
 @app.route('/members/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def members():
    error=None
    form = PostLink(request.form, csrf_enabled = False)
    uid = session['user_id']
    link = "NULL"
    groups = Links.query.filter_by(author_id=uid).all()

    if request.method=='POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            new_group = Links(
                       uid,
                       form.group.data,
                       link,
                       )
            try:
                   db.session.add(new_group)
                   db.session.commit()
                   flash("You have created a group!")
            except IntegrityError:
                    error = 'That group did not work, maybe it already exists?'
            else:
             flash_errors(form)
    return render_template('members.html', form=form, error=error, link = link, groups=groups)
```

And my 'members.html':

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

{% block content %}

```
  <p>Add New Group: {{ form.group }}</p>
  <input id="link" type="hidden" name="link" value= {{ link }}/>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Request"></p>
</form>
<br/>
{% for group in groups %}
<li><p>
{{ group }}
</p></li>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Currently this is just returning a list of links and groups in an odd format:

```
<Link u'link2'>

<Link u'linky'>

<Link u'linkymaybe'>

<Link u'madeit'>

<Link u'BLAH'>
```

So the core of my question is how do I build a query using SQLAlchemy to display all groups associated with the logged in user (uid = session['user_id']) I am pretty new to Flask and this problem is becoming an issue as I have tried a number of filter_by and filter statements with no luck at all.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is displaying correctly the object "Link" returned by the query.
You need to format it in the template.

```
Thisi is link {{ group.link }} from author #{{ group.author_id }} in group named {{ group.group }}
```

Maybe you've chosen a bad name "group" when cycling on results in the template. It should be called link.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. One more question. How can I filter the output to show no duplicate groups?

Answer (score 0):

In the template, you can show the group name using `{{ link.group }}` instead of `{{ link }}`. The query is returning the whole object.